# Dynamically Changing select box in jquery mobile not showing as selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, xcode4.2

```
$("#toCurrency option[value=" + $('#crrencycnvrtto').val() +"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

[image]

using the above code to assign selectbox dynamically not showing the proper value as selected. But when i am clicking on the selectbox it's showing that the option is selected.

Any idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using jquerymobile you should refresh your select box:

`$('#toCurrency').selectmenu('refresh');`